# PostgreSQL How to get friend requests in table by seeing if there is a duplicate of the reverse of a column?

Tags: postgresql, query

I've a table,

```
CREATE TABLE friends (
    friend1 serial references users(id),
    friend2 serial references users(id),
    unique (friend1, friend2)
);
```

Friends are in no particular order, but I need to have a query that returns friends where it is a one-way friendship. For example, if the data is:

```
friend1 | friend2
-----------------
1       | 2
2       | 1
3       | 2
```

the query for friend id=2 should return:

```
friend1 | friend2
-----------------
3       | 2
```

because there is not another row where friend1=2 and friend2=3.

Comment: `unique (friend1, friend2)` should probably be `PRIMARY KEY (friend1, friend2)`

Comment: @Jasen you are right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXCEPT to remove the complementing rows.

```
SELECT friend1,friend2 FROM friends 
    WHERE friend1=2 or friend2=2
EXCEPT
SELECT friend2,friend1 FROM friends
    WHERE friend1=2 or friend2=2;
```

But maybe using a CTE will perform better.

```
WITH buddies 
AS ( SELECT friend1,friend2 FROM friends 
        WHERE friend1=2 or friend2=2 )
SELECT friend1,friend2 FROM buddies
EXCEPT
SELECT friend2,friend1 FROM buddies
```

Unfolding the or into a union may help performance too.

```
WITH buddies 
AS ( SELECT friend1,friend2 FROM friends 
        WHERE friend1=2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT friend1,friend2 FROM friends 
        WHERE friend2=2
   )
SELECT friend1,friend2 FROM buddies
EXCEPT
SELECT friend2,friend1 FROM buddies
```